# Groups Acting on Sets ,Show that G can be embedded in Sn.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that H is a proper subgroup of G of index n, and that G is a simple group, that is, G has no normal subgroups except G itself and {1}. Show that G can be embedded in Sn.

here is what the sol manual say
The kernel of any homomorphism is a (normal) subgroup. If g ∈ ker Φ then
g(xH) = xH for every x ∈ G
, x−1gx ∈ H. Take x = g to get g ∈ H
 ker Φ is a normal subgroup of G, necessarily proper since it is contained
in H. Since G is simple, ker Φ = {1}, and hence Φ is injective. Since there are n left
cosets of H, Φ maps into Sn
can someone please explain

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What's the role of $H$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: i edited it, thank you

Comment: @wuestenfux I was wondering the same thing! my prof, gave me this quest and its confusing

Comment: I think the role of $H$ is to tell us that $n$ divides $|G|$. Because you clearly can't embed a group of order $k$ in $S_{k-1}$, for instance.

Comment: i asked my prof. he said that G act on left cosets of H by multiplication

Answer (score 0):

$G$ acts by left multiplication on the left quotient set $G/H$, of cardinal $n$ (by assumption on $H$). This is equivalent to a homomorphism $\Phi\colon G\to S_n$, necessarily injective because $G$ is simple and $\operatorname{ker}\Phi=$ $\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}\ne$ $G$ (being strictly $H<G$).